# RubyMotion UIScrollView does not scroll

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have set up my scroll view in my ProMotion screen `on_load` like this:

```
@scroll = add UIScrollView.alloc.initWithFrame(self.view.bounds)
i = 0
Card.all.each do |card|
    label = UILabel.new
    label.styleId = 'browse_detail'
    label.text =  card.name
    label.setFrame [[ 0 + (i * 320), 0 ], [ 320, 568 ]]
    add_to @scroll, label
    i = i+1
end

@scroll.frame = self.view.bounds
@scroll.pagingEnabled = true
@scroll.scrollEnabled = true
@scroll.contentSize = self.view.bounds.size;
```

The first card displays as a big red box with the correct text and my repl tree shows all the cards:

```
0: . UIWindow(#d05c2f0, [[0.0, 0.0], [320.0, 568.0]])
1: `-- PXUIView_UIView(#9a4ba50, [[0.0, 0.0], [320.0, 568.0]])
2:     `-- PXUIScrollView_UIScrollView(#9a4fe00, [[0.0, 0.0], [320.0, 568.0]])
3:         +-- PXUILabel_UILabel(#9a4ca50, [[0.0, 0.0], [320.0, 568.0]], text: "Live in the Now. Now!...")
4:         +-- PXUILabel_UILabel(#9a47c60, [[320.0, 0.0], [320.0, 568.0]], text: "I am a beutiful limit...")
5:         +-- PXUILabel_UILabel(#9a46cf0, [[640.0, 0.0], [320.0, 568.0]], text: "Live in the Now. Now!...")
6:         +-- PXUILabel_UILabel(#9a460b0, [[960.0, 0.0], [320.0, 568.0]], text: "Ruby Ruby Ruby!")
7:         +-- PXUILabel_UILabel(#9a45210, [[1280.0, 0.0], [320.0, 568.0]], text: "BAm Bam")
8:         +-- PXUIImageView_UIImageView(#9a4f0c0, [[0.0, 564.5], [320.0, 3.5]])
9:         `-- PXUIImageView_UIImageView(#9a3e580, [[316.5, 0.0], [3.5, 568.0]])
```

However I can't scroll. What am I missing? There are many other questions with similar problems. Generally the solution for them was to set the `contentSize` to a value less than the content width, but I think I have done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the exact content width (`i * 320`) have you tried setting the content size to that?

```
@scroll.contentSize = [i * 320.0, 568.0]
```

Testing that properly pages multiple horizontal views for me.

Comment: OH!  Thanks Dylan. For some reason i had it that the contentSize had to be set to less than the total width (so it is a window) but as you have it there, set to the total width of all the cards allows the horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
Set your contentsize to a small area, less than self.view.bounds.size

Or
Set scrollview bounce vertical to true, then it must be scrolling

Comment: Thanks for that.  making the bounds smaller didn't make a difference but setting @scroll.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true allows me to pull the screen accross and see a bit of the next screen, but it dosn't go any further.